# Tomcat 9 APR Connector Failed to initialize component java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9, apr, tcnative

I'm trying to use APR Connector with Tomcat 9.x according to the steps given in [Tomcat ans APR lib : requires the APR/native library which is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998811/tomcat-ans-apr-lib-requires-the-apr-native-library-which-is-not-available) to install APR native library. But I get the following error when running the application.

```
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector["https-openssl-apr-8443"]]
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.apache.tomcat.jni.Address.info(java.lang.String, int, int, int, long)'
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Address.info(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:361)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1332)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1345)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:75)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1009)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:554)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1039)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
```

Server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">
      <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2+TLSv1.3" sslProtocol="TLS">
           <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.p12"
                certificateKeystorePassword="password" certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12"/>
      </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Installed versions

- Java 11
- Apache Tomcat 9.0.84
- Tomcat Native 2.0.6
- Apache APR 1.7.4
- OS: MacOS 14.0 ARM

Other than the steps given in the link above, I used the follwoing environment variable in setenv.sh file since the given env was not working for me.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$CATALINA_HOME/lib"
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Tomcat Native 2.x if you use the APR connector. Stick to Tomcat Native 1.x.